# Proof of existence of an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

Assume $A$ is a complex $n \times n$ matrix such that 
$$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \, : \, \ker(\lambda I-A)$$
is the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{range}(\lambda I-A)$.

Show that there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

I tried to show $A$ is normal using the fact that $\ker(\lambda I-A)=\ker(\bar\lambda I-A^*)$ but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Hint: Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: You can show that $A(range( \lambda I -A)) \subset range( \lambda I -A)$ and then argue by induction on the dimension.

Comment: Slight correction: we have 
$$
\ker(\lambda I - A) = \ker (\bar \lambda I - A^*)
$$

Comment: $A$ is normal if and only if we have $\|Ax\| = \|A^*x\|$ for all $x$.  If we can indeed conclude that $A$ is normal given the information, this might be a useful intermediate step

Comment: @Paul are you trying to use the induction hypothesis for restriction of $A$ to $range(\lambda I-A)$? I do not see how $A|_{range(\lambda I-A)}$ satisfies the condition of the problem.

Comment: @user595419 Considering the rank nullity theorem and using the endomorphism $u $ canonically associated to A in the usual basis of $\mathbb {C} ^n$ which satisfy the same orthogonality condition of the kernel and image, it is enough to prove that given $x$ and $y$ in $Ker ( \mu I -u_{|F})$ and $Im ( \mu I -u_{|F })$ $x$ and $y $ are orthogonal. (Here $F=Im ( \lambda I-u) $)Which comes from the fact that the kernel and the image are just the one of $\mu I-u $ intersected with $F =Im ( \lambda I-u) $.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows.  With a [Schur-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is upper triangular.  Now, show that if $A$ is upper triangular and satisfies $\ker(\lambda I - A) = \ker(\bar \lambda - A^*)$, then it must be diagonal (and hence normal).

Comment: I was not able yo show that $A$ is diagonal. can you give me a hint please?